# Finding a specific file within a specific folder path within current working directory

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have a current directory say xyz inside which I would like to check where does the path src/app exists and if it does then check specific JSON file within src/app directory path and if so load the file.
Example of path: xyz/abc/src/app/sample.json
or xyz/src/app/sample.json

I have tried following:

```
import os
json_file = "sample.json"
dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
json_file _path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir, json_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question : if you're trying to check if a folder exists in you current directory you can use `os.path.exists()` which returns a boolean value.

If you're trying to display the directory path of a JSON file in that folder, you could write something like this :

```py
import os

filename = "sample.json"

directory = os.path.realpath(__file__)

if os.path.exists(f"src/app/{filename}"):
    json_file_path = directory + f"src/app/{filename}"
    print(json_file_path)
```

You may have notice I changed `dir` to `directory`, as it's good practice to avoid using function names as variable names.